# How to port knock RealVnc?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vnc, security

I have been having some trouble with port knocking my VNC, as when I nmap my rpi, the vnc ports are still open, here is my config file (excuse the lame sequence, I haven't fully set it up yet) :

```
[options]
    UseSyslog

[SSH]
    sequence    = 6000,7000,8000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 3197 -j 
    ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn
    cmd_timeout = 10
    stop_command = /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 3197 -j 
    ACCEPT

[openVNC1]
    sequence    = 8000,6000,4000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 3197 -j 
    ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn,ack

[closeVNC1]
    sequence    = 4000,6000,8000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 3197 -j 
    ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn,ack

 [openVNC2]
    sequence    = 3000,5000,7000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 3197 -j 
    ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn,ack

[closeVNC2]
    sequence    = 7000,5000,3000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 3197 -j 
ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn,ack
```

It still appears as open, and I can assess it too. This is strange, as it worked for my ssh. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

I got it to work, iptables was not being executed, nor was knockd as a service, unless you ran the knockd command. I fixed this by using a start file, and ufw.

I discovered that the iptables directory was not a thing, and it wan't being executed, so I was thinking about similar applications which allow you to do basically the same. So I thought, ufw.

I edited /etc/knockd.conf, and restarted it. This is what I was done:

```
[options]
    logfile = /var/log/knockd.log
    interface = wlan0
[SSH]
    sequence    = 0001:tcp,0021:udp,1011:udp
    tcpflags = syn
    seq_timeout = 15
    start_command = ufw allow 3197
    cmd_timeout = 10
    stop_command = ufw deny 3197

[VNC1]
    sequence    = 3002:udp,5000:udp,2892:tcp
    tcpflags = syn
    seq_timeout = 15
    start_command = ufw allow 5900
    cmd_timeout = 25
    stop_command = ufw deny 5900

[VNC2]
    sequence    = 3003:udp,9083:tcp,8909:udp
    tcpflags = syn
    seq_timeout = 15
    start_command = ufw allow 5901
    cmd_timeout = 25
    stop_command = ufw deny 5901
```

I made a file in /etc/init.d/ , and named it startup.sh, I followed this guide: 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html

This is what I wrote:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiYpx.jpg

Basically, it resets the firewall on startup, and then sets the allowed ports for my pi, and puts it in the background, just like a service.

After this, reboot your pi, and it should all work! This is a nice workaround and overall efficiency.

**Solution 2**

Well. a friend found out this link, just do it from here instead: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-use-port-knocking-to-hide-the-ssh-port-from-attackers-on-ubuntu

Have fun not being paranoid!

---

<sup><sub>Posted by the OP as an edit to the question.</sub></sup>